# How to search for certain strings within an Arraylist

Tags: java, string

Firstly I would like to thank the community here on their help so far.

In a method I have to write the instructions state that I have to find a Fragment whose name includes key.

```
ArrayList<Fragment> collage;
```

Now, i have experiment with `indexOf` and `.contains` in this method, but I cannot figure it out.
I figure you have to make a string with the value "key"

```
String str = "key";
```

Then use indexOf to find the index at which "key" is found? is this right, or does indexOf work only in strings?
Can anyone help point me in the right direction here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do that directly in a `List`; at least not with Java 7. With Java 8 you could use `.stream().allMatch()`. With Java 7 you have to loop and extract; or if you use Guava, `Iterables.filter()` through a `Predicate`

Comment: You will not be able to find a `String` in a list of `Fragment`s.

Comment: "or does indexOf work only in strings" ... it uses the `equals` method, so it does not *only* work on Strings. However, a `Fragment` will most likely not be equal to a `String`.

Comment: Maybe a little more code would be helpful. Could you add the code for the Fragment?

Comment: Just iterate the ArrayList<Fragment> then on each iteration check your string with .equals() so you will get appropriate result.

Answer (score 1):

In List all elements are stored in the insertion order. So in order to get that order you can use `indexOf()` method which returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list.To check whether a particular String exists in the List or not you use `contains()`. It simply returns a boolean value and has nothing to do with order/index or number of time element occurs in the List.

Comment: Are stored _in insertion order_. That is an important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple `for` loop:

```
ArrayList<Fragment> collage = new ArrayList<String>();
//...
for (Fragmenttmp: collage){
    if (tmp.name.equals(key))
        //do something
}
```

However I suggest you to use a `HashMap` :

```
HashMap<String, Fragment> collage = new HashMap<String, Fragment>();
//...
collage.get(key);
```